# Event ID 3009 on SBS 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003, activesync, eventviewer

Getting the following error on my SBS 2003 R2 Server:

Server ActiveSync:

Unexpected Exchange mailbox Server error: Server: [celeritympp.mpp1.local] User: [jwhalen@mpp1.com] HTTP status code: [409]. Verify that the Exchange mailbox Server is working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context would be helpful... is that message in the event log? any guess as to what generates it? Try using this tool to analyze your exchange services:

https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

It can identify many common configuration issues and point you in the right direction for fixes.